# Flask CORS and Flask Limiter

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, flask-cors

I am using flask cors, flask limiter and AngularJS for my web-app.. Everything is working fine but what I want is too return a 429 too many request message on the front-end but I can't seem to do that because the OPTIONS methods blocks everything once it returns a 429

My AngularJS error response code:

```
function(response){
    var res_data = (response.data && response.data.data) ? response.data.data : null;
    var res_status = response.status;
    FlashService.Error(response[keys.issue_fields], true);
    if (res_status == 513 && res_data && res_data[keys.issue_fields][0] == keys.email) {
        vm.error = "Your email is not recognized. Please try again.";
    } else if (res_status == 513 && res_data && res_data[keys.issue_fields][0] == keys.password){
        vm.error = "Your email and password combination was incorrect. Please try again.";
    } else if (res_status == 513 && res_data && res_data[keys.issue_fields][0] == keys.suspension){
        vm.error = "Your account is inactive.";
    }else if (res_status == 429) {
        vm.error = "You have attempted a numerous login failed attempt.. Please try again later.";
    }else if (res_status == -1) {
        vm.error = "Server Error. Please try again later.";
    }else {
        vm.error = "Your email and password combination was incorrect. Please try again.";
    }
    vm.dataLoading = false;
});
```

This is my flask code:

```
@user_manager.route('/login/dp', methods=['POST'])
#make sure limit_key is changed if modify limit since it is hard coded
@limiter.limit("5/15minute")
def login_dp():
    if key.email() in request.form and key.password() in request.form:
        user_id = CBDPUserDatabase().login(request.form[key.email()], request.form[key.password()])
        if user_id > 0:
            limit_key = 'LIMITER/%s/%s/10/15/minute' %  (get_ipaddr(), request.endpoint)
            if limit_key in limiter._storage.storage: del limiter._storage.storage[limit_key]
            if limit_key in limiter._storage.expirations: del limiter._storage.expirations[limit_key]
            user_profile = CBDPUserDatabase().fetch_user_profile(user_id)
            token = create_dp_token(user_id, user_profile[key.dealership()][key.id()])
            if user_profile is not None:
                return ResponsePacket.success(data={key.profile(): user_profile, key.token(): token})
            else:
                # Couldn't retrieve the user's profile
                return ResponsePacket.data_exception(data={key.issue_fields(): [key.profile()]})
        elif user_id == -2:
            # Email address not found in user database
            return ResponsePacket.data_exception(data={key.issue_fields(): [key.email()]})
        elif user_id == -3:
            # Password given does not match
            return ResponsePacket.data_exception(data={key.issue_fields(): [key.password()]})
        elif user_id == -4:
            return ResponsePacket.data_exception(data={key.issue_fields(): [key.suspension()]})

    else:
        return ResponsePacket.request_exception()
```

This is my CORS setup:

```
cors = CORS(application, resources={r"*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

Here is my flask logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2016 08:10:02] "OPTIONS /user/login/dp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2016 08:10:04] "POST /user/login/dp HTTP/1.1" 513 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2016 08:10:06] "POST /user/login/dp HTTP/1.1" 513 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2016 08:10:07] "POST /user/login/dp HTTP/1.1" 513 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2016 08:10:08] "OPTIONS /user/login/dp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2016 08:10:08] "POST /user/login/dp HTTP/1.1" 429 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2016 08:10:10] "POST /user/login/dp HTTP/1.1" 429 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2016 08:10:13] "OPTIONS /user/login/dp HTTP/1.1" 429 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2016 08:10:22] "OPTIONS /user/login/dp HTTP/1.1" 429 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2016 08:10:24] "OPTIONS /user/login/dp HTTP/1.1" 429 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2016 08:10:24] "OPTIONS /user/login/dp HTTP/1.1" 429 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2016 08:10:26] "OPTIONS /user/login/dp HTTP/1.1" 429 -
```

Here is my web console

[image]

Comment: The preflight requests are sent out for any cross domain requests by the browser when the application attempts to make any sort of GET or POST request.  If the preflight doesn't come back 200 OK the corresponding GET or POST or whatever won't actually get sent.  It seems like the problem here is on the flask limiter side of things since after it has given a 429 response to the post it is now responding to the OPTIONS requests made by the browser with 429, seems like something needs to be reset there on the limiter or the limiter needs to be limited to only particular routes you want to block.

Comment: Any technical suggestions?

Comment: sorry I don't know Python or Flask for that matter to tell you what to try there really but just saying this is mostly something that the browser and server have to work out angular itself doesn't really have a hand in it aside from initiating the request but really the browser is the one responsible for sending the OPTIONS request and the flask server or whatever it hits server side to respond to those appropriately.

Comment: Yeah, I agree,, So right now I'm having a problem segregating the error message from server down and too many requests because of status returning is -1

Answer (score 0):

I got it now! Just put a methods parameter

```
@limiter.limit("20/15minute", methods=['POST'])
```